# Show array in listbox

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, tkinter, listbox

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?! I made a GUI with tkinter in Python 3. **I am tring to create array and show it to listbox when the window opens.** Below, you can see code that I used.

**ERROR**:

```
Population.X[i] = float(random.random()) * self.XMin
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

**CODE:**

```
class Population:
    X = []
    Y = []

class Application(Frame):
   def __init__(self, master):
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.widgets()
        self.create_array()

   def widgets(self):
        self.first_listbox = Listbox(self)
        self.first_listbox.grid()

   def create_array(self):
        i = 0
        while i < 20:
            Population.X[i] = float(random.random()) * self.XMin
            # x = random.random() - Random float x | 0.0 <= x < 1.0 |
            if Population.X[i] == 0:
                Population.X[i] = -0.1
            Population.Y[i] = 1 / Population.X[i]
            i += 1
        while i < 20:
            self.first_listbox.insert(i, Population.X[i])
            i += 1

root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Appending to a list

You get an `IndexError` because you're trying to access element number `0` while your list has no element.

You can't create a new index like this:

```
my_list = []
my_list[12] = 'whatever'
```

But you can append to the list iteratively:

```
def create_array(self):

    for i in range(20):

        new_item = float(random.random()) * self.XMin)

        if new_item == 0:
            new_item = -0.1

        Population.X.append(new_item)
        Population.Y.append(1 / new_item)
```

#### Filling the listbox

Also, this part of your code would never be reached:

```
    while i < 20:
        self.first_listbox.insert(i, Population.X[i])
        i += 1
```

because `i` is `20` when getting out of the former loop. You'd need to set `i` back to `0` or better to rethink the whole thing:

```
for item in Population.X:
    self.first_listbox.insert(END, item)
```

#### Minor style remark

Note that

```
        new_item = float(random.random()) * self.XMin)

        if new_item == 0:
            new_item = -0.1
```

could be written in one line:

```
        new_item = float(random.random()) * self.XMin) or -0.1
```

but the former is totally fine and easier to grasp. It is mostly a matter of taste.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer! I need to say that I am new in Python, still have Java developers thinking style. Need more practice in Python. Have a good day! =)